# Equivalent of shift tab for Notes on macOS

Tags: keyboard

How do I achieve this,

```
hello
    how
```

to,

```
hello
how
```

that is I want to reverse tab.

On Notes, I select `how`, then press `shift + tab`

it does nothing.

it does not reverse tab.

Comment: Shift/Tab is the opposite of Tab on Mac too. It reverses direction.

Comment: it does not work on Notes app

Comment: Please be clear exactly what your question is. What do you expect to happen, what happens instead. We cannot see over your shoulder.

Comment: updated it now.

Comment: You mean for indentation… or…?

Comment: yes, indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes doesn't use  <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   for indentation, it uses  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>]</kbd>  &  <kbd>[</kbd>

<kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   sometimes works, but it acts more like a 'true' Tab, ie it will work on a single word in the middle of a line, rather than the entire line, & doesn't have an inverse. It will work on lists but not plain text.

Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>]</kbd>  &  <kbd>[</kbd>  instead, for predictable behaviour.

Comment: yes it works, but that is not exactly what I want, I would like to keep the text selected and press tab to move a block forward, while press shift tab to move a block backward, maybe it is not a Notes thing. I use it in a programming IDE, that is Google Colab, so maybe should not expect Notes to work similarly.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work like that. If you use key command replacements you'll lose the distinction & Tab will *always* shift the entire line… not always what you want.